Sitecore 9.3 Analytics API to get the total Visits and unique visits from last 30days
Could someone share the sample analytics api to retrieve the analytics data to get the total Visits and unique visits from last 30 days.

Solution 1:
The code below will return your contact facets and related interactions.
var contactCursor = await client.CreateContactEnumerator(
                        new ContactEnumeratorOptions(
                            new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey)
                            {
                                Interactions = new RelatedInteractionsExpandOptions(IpInfo.DefaultFacetKey)
                                {
                                    StartDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-300),
                                    EndDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-200)
                                }
                            })
                        {
                            BatchSize = 200
                        });
var totalContactsCount = contactCursor.TotalCount;

Results are returned in batches of 200. You can use the MoveNext() method for the next batch size.
The above will result in the TotalContactsCount, which will also have the same multiple entries of the same contact ID.
Using lambda expression get the distinct count.
 var totalContactsCount = contactCursor.Current.Select(i => i.Id).Distinct().Count();

see the document for more details: Extracting contacts
Solution 2:
You can also use Analytics Database Manager (ADM) provided by Sitecore.
The Analytics Database Manager (ADM) is a module that allows performing various operations with the collection database, such as:

Removing contacts and interactions data.
Viewing database statistics.
Rebuild calculated facets.

See the documentation for more details: Analytics Database Manager (ADM)

You can leverage Reporting API to retrieve total visits and unique visits from the [Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics] table inside the Reporting table as shown below.
In order to retrieve visits and total visits for last 30 days, we can run below query which joins the Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics, DimensionKeys and Fact_SystemMetrics table to retrieve corresponding results.
    using Sitecore.Xdb.Reporting;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Sitecore.Configuration;
    
    public static Tuple<int,int> GetTotalVisits(){
      var provider = (ReportDataProvider)Factory.CreateObject("reporting/dataProvider", true);
      var query = new ReportDataQuery("SELECT sum([Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics].Visits) as Visits, sum(Fact_SystemMetrics.TotalVisits) as TotalVisits FROM [sitecorehackaton2024_Reporting].[dbo].[Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics] INNER JOIN [DimensionKeys] on [DimensionKeys].DimensionKeyId = Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics.DimensionKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Fact_SystemMetrics WHERE [SegmentId] IN ('424110F4-2B2B-4453-9E2B-635E1DE75F20')) As Fact_SystemMetrics ON Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics.[SiteNameId] = Fact_SystemMetrics.[SiteNameId] AND Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics.[Date] = Fact_SystemMetrics.[Date] AND Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics.[FilterId] = Fact_SystemMetrics.[FilterId]  Where [Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics].SegmentId = '56649EAC-3CCF-4EAB-88B0-C74862DB862B' and [Fact_ChannelGroupMetrics].Date > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())");
      string datasource = "reporting";
      ReportDataResponse response = provider.GetData(datasource, query, new CachingPolicy { NoCache = true });
      var datatable = response.GetDataTable();
      if (datatable != null && datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         var visits = datatable.Rows[0]["Visits"];
         var totalVisits = datatable.Rows[0]["TotalVisits"];
         return Tuple.Create(visits, totalVisits);
      }
      return null;
     }

Using above query we can also fetch total time on site,total page views, monetary value etc.
You can find more details on the reporting api here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/reporting-api.html
Hope this helps!!!

thanks for the answer, I get the exception. Column 'UniqueVisits' does not belong to table

DId you checked the datatable response..is it containing UniqueVisits column in the response...Also is it working at your end for 1st case i.e. for TotalVisits?

Thank you I see it, but the query doesnt seem to get unique visits? .  Also the total visits doesnt match the total visits inside the launch pad's experience analytics. Any thoughts

@sns Second Query is to get the total unique visits which will match the number you see on the dashboard...Did you tryed to run this query on the SQL?

@sns Did you tried running second query..Are you still getting any issues?

Only concern I have here is, in the experience editor page_visits doesnt match this page_visits.

@sns can you please let me know where you are checking page_visits inside experience editor.

@sns I have updated the query above to fetch the visits and total visits.. Let me know in case you face any issues.

can you elaborate on the difference between visits and total visits? Im looking for Total visits in a week and unique visits.

@sns I believe visits and total visits are same. Its just named differently in both the tables. A visit is couted from the moment user enter a website until the moment they leave. Therefore the count of visits will include unique users only.
In case you are interested in fetching page views,then above query gives total pageviews as well.

@sns I just checked 'Visits' in the above query return visits through online channel and 'Total Visits' returns visits through online as well as offline channel. You can find more details on visits(https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/the-dimensions-and-metrics-in-experience-analytics-reports.html) and channels(https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/channels.html) here. Hope this solves the issue you raised!!!

Using the Sitecore reporting database the Sitecore analytics API comes with some handy features to achieve this with the reporting database.
There are lot's of out of the box report queries that you can find under this location.
/sitecore/system/Settings/Content Testing/Report Queries

Here is the sample query to get the visits from the OOTB report queries.
DECLARE
    @LanguageCode int = null,
    @DeviceCode int = null
    
IF @LanguageName != ''
BEGIN
    SELECT @LanguageCode = LanguageId
    FROM [Languages]
    WHERE Name = @LanguageName
END

IF @DeviceName != ''
BEGIN
    SELECT @DeviceCode = DeviceNameId
    FROM [DeviceNames]
    WHERE DeviceName = @DeviceName
END

SELECT
    SUM([Visits]) AS [Visits]
FROM
    dbo.[Fact_PageViewsByLanguage]
WHERE
    [ItemId] = @ItemId 
    AND [LanguageId] = COALESCE(@LanguageCode, LanguageId)
    AND [DeviceNameId] = COALESCE(@DeviceCode, DeviceNameId)
    AND [Date] >= @Start 
    AND [Date] <= @End

You can modify this as per your need.
Also you can follow this article to know more about querying them.
https://theroks.com/use-sitecore-analytics-show-number-pageviews/#:~:text=Second%20is%20the%20query%20field,to%20be%20a%20negative%20number.
Hope this helps.
