How to get unique visitors in sitecore 9.3
Is there an API available to retrieve the unique visitors for a site within a specific month?

Are you looking for Rest API's to be called to fetch this data and will this api be called on CD or CM server?

Im looking for reporting api to fetch the unique visitors. This is run in CM @ckhanna

Db reporting api

I thnk I answered it here on one of your question raised earlier..https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/37542/sitecore-9-3-analytics-api-to-get-the-total-visits-and-unique-visits-from-last-3...Are you looking for something different?

@ckhanna do you have a better solution, In that solution both visitors and visits coming out as same number

@sns I have updated answer with another solution, hope that helps you.

@sns sure let me check...I will come back to you on this by this weekend.

Solution 1:
The code below will return your contact facets and related interactions.
var contactCursor = await client.CreateContactEnumerator(
                        new ContactEnumeratorOptions(
                            new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey)
                            {
                                Interactions = new RelatedInteractionsExpandOptions(IpInfo.DefaultFacetKey)
                                {
                                    StartDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-300),
                                    EndDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-200)
                                }
                            })
                        {
                            BatchSize = 200
                        });
var totalContactsCount = contactCursor.TotalCount;

Results are returned in batches of 200. You can use the MoveNext() method for the next batch size.
The above will result in the TotalContactsCount, which will also have the same multiple entries of the same contact ID.
Using lambda expression get the distinct count.
 var totalContactsCount = contactCursor.Current.Select(i => i.Id).Distinct().Count();

see the document for more details: Extracting contacts
Solution 2:
You can also use Analytics Database Manager (ADM) provided by Sitecore.
The Analytics Database Manager (ADM) is a module that allows performing various operations with the collection database, such as:

Removing contacts and interactions data.
Viewing database statistics.
Rebuild calculated facets.

See the documentation for more details: Analytics Database Manager (ADM)
